# Change the PATH variable with bat?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

i'm trying to write 2 BATCH tools which cahnges my system variable path.
The first one should add a destination in front of the Path but save the old Path in a txt file before, and the second BATCH file should load the Path from the txt file and replace the Path with the saved one to restore the old path again.

```
@echo. 2>%date:~0%_PATH.txt
@echo %PATH% >> %date:~0%_PATH.txt
@echo "This tool will change the system variable PATH"
@echo "if you want to continue, press any key."
@echo "To cancel press CTRL+C"
@pause

@setx /m PATH  "C:\MinGW\bin;%PATH%"
@echo.
@echo.
@echo "The System variables has been set"
@echo "Your original PATH variable was saved to: %date:~0%_PATH.txt"

@pause
```

This is the first batch file which should add C:\MinGW\bin in front of the PATH. (It is not doint that, after i run the batch file there is much more than just my Destination.

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO "You are about to restore your system variable PATH to a previous state!"
ECHO "If you want to preform this step, press any key."
ECHO "To cancel the process, press CTRL+C";
ECHO.
SET index=1

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%f IN (*.*) DO (
   SET file!index!=%%f
   ECHO !index! - %%f
   SET /A index=!index!+1
)

SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET /p selection="Please select by typing the number which file you want to recover      your PATH:"

SET file%selection% > nul 2>&1

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   ECHO Invalid number selected!!  
   EXIT /B 1
)

CALL :RESOLVE %%file%selection%%%
ECHO Selected file name: %file_name%

GOTO :EOF

:RESOLVE
SET file_name=%1
GOTO :EOF

@setx /m PATH %file_name%
```

And this is the restore batch file which will not select my choosen file.

I hope anybody can help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SETX` only changes the value in the registry, not the variable in the current shell environment.  As the documentation says when you run `SETX /?`:

```
NOTE: 1) SETX writes variables to the master environment in the registry.
      2) On a local system, variables created or modified by this tool
         will be available in future command windows but not in the
         current CMD.exe command window.
```

If you only want to modify the value of PATH in current environment just use the regular `SET` command. If you want to do both, then you'll need to use both commands.

Comment: For what reason would you want to set a variable in the registry?  Does that make it persistent somehow or something?

Comment: Yes, that's where the environment variable get their initial values.